# How to initialize a string?

Tags: java, string, initialization

```
String car; 

    if (type == 'E')
        {fee = rate*50;
         car = "Economy";}

    else if (type == 'M')
         {fee = rate*70;
         car = "Midsize";}


    else if (type == 'F')
        {fee = rate*100;
        car = "Fullsize";}

System.out.println("Car type is " + car);
```

This is the part of my program that i have problem with. I get 'local variable car may not have been initialized ' . What should i do to make 'car' initialized ?

Comment: What about if type is not equals to `E`, `M` or `F` ? Just initialize it with `String car = "";`

Comment: This is a situation where you should really use an `enum` for your `E`, `M`, and `F` values; you can assign names, descriptions, rates, and so on to the enum values, and it makes your code cleaner, safer, and more maintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java can't guarantee that `car` will ever become initialized.  You don't have a guaranteed case (`else`) in your `if` statement that assigns `car`.

Initialize it to some value, such as an empty string.

```
String car = "";
```

Comment: Is it good practice to always initialize your string variables to empty instead of null?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you set your String to `null` to solve the compilation error.

```
String car = null;
```

That is because Java is trying to protect you from doing something you don't expect. If all the `if` statements are not executed, the variable will not get assigned. To tell Java, that you know that this might happen, you just chose explicitly to set it to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Java can't tell what's going to happen with your variable reach print, as it's initially pointing nowhere and further initializations are enclosed in conditionals
Set your car variable  to a default value depending on logic: "" or null are good options but it's really up to you in the end

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to do this another way:

```
switch (type) {
 case 'E':
    fee =rate* 50;
    car = "Economy";
    break;
 case 'M':
    fee =rate* 70;
    car = "Economy";
    break;
 case 'F':
    fee =rate*100;
    car = "Economy";
    break;
 default:
    fee = 0;
    car = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would of solved this problem using an inner `Enum` class.

```
public class EnumExample {
    public enum CarType {
        E( 50,"Economy" ),
        F( 70, "Midsize" ),
        M( 100, "Fullsize");
        // Add as many as you want

        private int cost;
        private String type;

        CarType(int theCost, String theType) {
            cost = theCost;
            type = theType;
        }

        public int getFee(int rate) {
            return rate*cost;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return type;
        }
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String type = "E";
        int rate = 25;

        switch( CarType.valueOf( type ) ) {
            case E:
                System.out.println( "The Car Type is: " + CarType.E );
                System.out.println( "The fee is: " + CarType.E.getFee(rate) );
                break;
            case F:
                System.out.println( "The Car Type is: " + CarType.F );
                System.out.println( "The fee is: " + CarType.F.getFee(rate) );
                break;
            case M:
                // ETC
            default:
                // Use a switch/case so you can add 'no car type' e.g Fee = 0;
        }
    }
}
```